# True or False: f(n) = O(max(f(n), o(f(n)))

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I can't seem to figure this one out. Theres a lot of similar examples but none with this exact problem.
I need to determine if the statement is true or false:
f(n) = O(max(f(n), o(f(n)))

Is anyone able to help me out?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `g(n) = o(f(n))`, it means `lim(g(n)/f(n)) = 0, n -> \infty`. Hence, for a constant `n0`, we have `f(n) > g(n)` for all `n > n0`. Therefore, `max(f(n), g(n)) = f(n)` for all `n > n0` and `f(n) = O(f(n))`. As the latter is always true, the statement is true.